# If convergence in distribution, then the probability generating functions converge pointwise

Tags: limits, transformation

I have some trouble with the following problem:

"Let $X,X_1,X_2,...$ be non-negative integer-valued random variables. Show that if $X_n \overset{d}{\to} X$ and X is almost surely finite, then the probability generating functions converge pointwise on $[0,1]$, that is $g_{X_n}(t) \to g_X(t)$ for $t\in[0,1]$."

I feel confused with the sentence "X is almost surely finite", do they mean that $X\overset{a.s}{\to}c$ if $c<\infty$?

I would be most grateful if someone could translate that sentence and at least give me a hint on how to start solving this problem.

Comment: $X$ being finite a.s. means that $\Pr ( X < \infty ) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, that was easier than I thought, I was thinking about the meaning of that sentence from the wrong angle it seems. 
How would you start to solve this problem though? Any ideas?

Comment: I would start by writing down the definition of convergence in distribution, and any conditions I know equivalent to it. I would also write down the definition of the probability generating function and see if any of the things I know about convergence in distribution would help.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. I've found a theorem that says that if we have convergence in the tranforms then we have $X_n \overset{d}{\to}X$. But there's no proof given, so I'm still not sure on how I should prove this "reversed" problem.

Answer (score 1):

$X_n \overset{d} \rightarrow X$ means that for all continuous and bounded functions $f$ we have
$$\Bbb E [f(X_n)] \rightarrow \Bbb E [f(X)].$$
Fix $t\in[0,1]$. Choose $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R, x \mapsto t^x$. Therefore,
$$g_{X_n} (t) = \Bbb E [t^{X_n}] \to \Bbb E [t^{X}] = g_X (t).$$